# Amazon S3 replication to multiple destination buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 replication rules in a bucket with overlapping objects, which should result in the data being replicated to 2 different destination buckets.

By default, priorities 1 & 2 are attributed to them causing the second replication to not apply.

How do I set the priority if I want to have both applied?

Answer (score 1):

Rule Priority should not be interfering with replication to [different destination
buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-replication-adds-support-for-multiple-destination-buckets/):

> rule priorities are used when there are two or more rules with the same destination. When that happens, the rule with the highest priority will be applied. For the same destination bucket, a lower priority rule will not be applied when the replication configuration has two or more rules with overlapping scope. **If there are two or more rules with the same scope and different destinations, both rules will be applied**.

So there must be another root cause.  Double-check the rule definition and permissions. And I'm sure you know this, but replication rules only apply to objects created *after* a rule is added.